# Simples chat jquey com banco de dados em html - Como enviar form apertando a tecla enter

Tags: php, jquery, html

Bom estou tentando minimizar ao maximo como esta bem pequeno vou postar o meu codigo inteiro, me deparei com um problema o codigo esta funcionando perfeitamente, porem so quando clico no button enviar que funciona, gostaria de saber como fazer para que funcione apertando a tecla enter ou clicando.OBS:Não manjo muito de jquery

index.html

```
 <div id="chat"></div><br />
  <form action="#" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" id="nome" value="<?=$usuario?>" size="6">
  <input type="text" id="mensagem" width="80%" >
  <button type="button" id="enviar" title="enviar" >Enter</button>
  </form>
```

chat.php

```
<?php
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];
$linha = $nome.' - '.$mensagem.'<br>';
$arquivo = file('chatlog.htm');
array_unshift($arquivo, $linha);
file_put_contents('chatlog.htm', $arquivo);
?>
```

script

```
  $(function() {
conversar();
$('#enviar').click(function() {
    var nome = $('#nome').val();
    var mensagem = $('#mensagem').val();
    $.post('chat.php', {'nome':nome, 'mensagem': mensagem }, function() {
      conversar;
    $('#mensagem').val('');
    });
});

function conversar() {
  $('#chat').load('chatlog.htm');
  $('#mensagem').focus();
}
setInterval(conversar, 3000);
});
```

css

```
 #chat {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    border: black 1px solid;
    background-color: #000000;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll; 
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
   }
   fieldset {
    width: 330px;
    background-color: #e6e2af;
    border: black 1px solid;
   }
```

os dados sao salvos num arquivo de nome chatlog.htm

Comment: Ao inves de type button experimente type submit, no Chrome rodou legal <button type="submit" id="enviar" title="enviar" >Enter</button>``

Answer (score 4):

Uma boa opção será criar uma função em JavaScript para responder aos eventos 
de `keypress` no `input` onde se digita a mensagem:

```
function enviarEnter(e){
    var tecla=(window.event)?event.keyCode:e.which;
    if (tecla == 13)
    {
        //coloca se o que precisa fazer, ex: função ajax;
    }
}
```

E no `input` ficaria assim:

```
<input type="text" id="mensagem" onkeypress="enviaEnter(event)"/>
```

Dessa forma a cada tecla pressionada ele vai verificar se a tecla primida foi um <kbd>Enter</kbd> e se for o caso, ele irá executar a função.

Comment: tentei o seguinte $(document).ready(function() {
 $(#mensagem).bind('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==13){
    $('#enviar').trigger('click');
        }
        });
});

porem sem resultado quando aperto enter conteidnua atualizando a pagina ao inves de chamar o jquery

Comment: Qual navegador esta usando?

Comment: chorme e mozila

Comment: Ja tentou no internet explorer, se nao me engano KeyCode não funciona no mozilla, testa pra sabermos.

Comment: mesma coisa, quando  dou enter atualiza a pagina inteira. caso queira ver na pratica http://yugioh.site

Comment: Entao faz o seguinte, para teste: na função que passei pra vc, insere dentro dela o codigo que esta dentro do click do botao enviar, depois no evento keypress do input mensagem vc coloca enviaEnter(event);

Comment: rapaz, eu alterei aqui troquei o <button type="button" id="enviar" title="enviar" >Enter</button> por <input type="text" id="enviar" value="enviar" > e por incrivel que pareça o enter passou a funcionar agora so nao me pergunte o porque, creio que deve ter algo a ver com a tag button so pode

Comment: Que bom,, Verifica se vai rodar em todos os navegadores...

Comment: rodou sim, mais o misterio ainda continua

Answer (score 0):

> Sobre o atributo type dos buttons

1. submit: O botão envia os dados do formulário para o servidor.
2. button: O botão não possui comportamento padrão. Ele pode ter scripts do lado do cliente associado com os eventos do elemento, no qual são acionados quando o evento ocorrer.

> Use o type submit que a tecla enter vai funcionar!

```
<button type="submit" id="enviar" title="enviar" >Enter</button>
```